# Error in the code KnownCoordinateSystems.Projected.CoordinateSystems

Tags: vb.net

My code is generating an exception. That exception is: [insert your exception message and stack trace here].

Here is the class that I am using that is generating the above exception:

```vb
    Imports GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems
    Imports GeoAPI.CoordinateSystems.Transformations
    Imports ProjNet.CoordinateSystems
    Imports ProjNet.Converters
    Imports ProjNet.Converters.WellKnownText
    Imports GMap.NET
    Imports GMap.NET.MapProviders
    Imports GMap.NET.WindowsForms
    Imports GMap.NET.WindowsForms.Markers
    Imports DotSpatial.Projections

    Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
       GMapControl1.MapProvider = GMapProviders.GoogleMap
       GMapControl1.Position = New PointLatLng(29.32206, 47.65384)
       GMapControl1.Zoom = 10
       AddHandler GMapControl1.MouseMove, AddressOf GMapControl1_MouseMove
    End Sub

    Private Sub GMapControl1_MouseMove(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
       Dim point As PointLatLng = GMapControl1.FromLocalToLatLng(e.X, e.Y)
       Dim mgrs As String = ConvertLatLngToMGRS(point.Lat, point.Lng)
       TextBox3.Text = mgrs
    End Sub

    Private Function ConvertLatLngToMGRS(latitude As Double, longitude As Double) As String
       Dim utmZone As Integer = CInt(Math.Floor((longitude + 180) / 6) + 1)
       Dim utmZoneChar As Char = If(latitude \>= 0, ChrW(65 + ((utmZone - 1) Mod 8)), 
       ChrW(65 +((utmZone - 1) Mod 8) + 8))
       Dim xy() As Double = {longitude, latitude} 
       Dim z() As Double
       Dim wgs84 As ProjectionInfo = KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984
       KnownCoordinateSystems.Projected.CoordinateSystems.ProjectedCoordinateSystems.UTM
       (zone:=utmZone,northHemi:=latitude \>= 0
       Reproject.ReprojectPoints(xy, z, wgs84, utm, 0, 1)  
       Dim mgrs As String = UtmCoordsToMGRS(xy(0), xy(1), utmZone, utmZoneChar)
       Return mgrs
    End Function

    Private Function UtmCoordsToMGRS(x As Double, y As Double, utmZone As Integer, utmZoneChar As   
Char) As String
       Dim mgrs As String = String.Format("{0}{1:D2} {2}{3:00000} {4}{5:00000}", utmZone,    
       Math.Floor(Math.Abs(y) / 100000), utmZoneChar, x Mod 100000, "A", y Mod 100000)
       Return mgrs
    End Function

    End Class
```

I added libraries to the project
1-DotSpatial
2-GMap
3-ProjNET4GeoAPI

Comment: The program is required to output the coordinates  38R TQ 44000 55000

Comment: Please edit your OP and include any exception messages you are receiving. If you are not getting an exception, please describe what you are experiencing that is undesired and what should instead happen. Include any sample data/parameters being used to generate the incorrect output.

Comment: Error BC30456 'UTM' is not a member of 'UtmWgs1984'

Comment: That's not an exception, it's a compile-time error.  It looks like the issue is with the line immediately following the assignment to `wgs84` which looks garbled.  I'd recommend to check the documentation for `ProjectedCoordinateSystems` as the error indicates that you are not using it correctly.

Comment: Also, consider adding an appropriate tag for the geographical library, as people knowledgeable in that library are not likely to follow the VB tag.